# WinForms: Capture clicks on PDF hosted in a WebBrowser control

Tags: winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

Bottom line question: how can I capture click events from a PDF hosted in a WinForms WebBrowser control?

I am writing a WinForms application, showing a PDF in a WebBrowser control. The PDF is generated by me. I would like to put links in that PDF, so that when clicked the WinForms application will get notified and take actions according to information in the links.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Using `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event to register with the `WebBrowser.Document.Click`. This doesn't work because navigating to a PDF leaves WebBrowser.Document null (see [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1032467)).
2. Using `WebBrowser.NewWindow` event to capture it trying to open a browser window with my link. Didn't work. I guess that the PDF application communicates with the OS directly (?).
3. Using AcroPdfLib instead of WebBrowser. AxAcroPdf doesn't raise any relevant events.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Did you got any solution ?

Comment: No. We will probably buy this: https://pdfium.patagames.com/. I tested their library and it seems to do what we need. Also they are not too expensive.

Comment: Okay .we were using DevExpress .in devExpress have PDFViewer . that PDFViewer have mouse click event.so now its fine for me .